# Configuring log4j for a specific user

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j

Hi I am using log4j in my J2EE application, I have a scenario of enabling logging details of a particular user and write his log details in  separate file.

Is there any way to implement this.

```
any help will be appreciated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways, but you can't do it by configuration.

You need to write your own appender extending an existing Appender class (for example FileAppender or RollingFileAppender) and to override at least "public void activateOptions()" to set the file according to the current user.